# how to call API from axios with header

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to call the API **POST** method with **axios**, I did it with postman with header configuration like, and it return the results  [image]

and the body request looks : [image]

it return error when I call by axios this my script, anyone can help me what I suppose todo from the axios side ?

```
const header = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Transfer-Encoding': 'application/json',
                'content-type': 'application/json',
                'HTTP_API_KEY': 'xxxxx',
            }
        }
        axios({
            method: 'POST',
            url: URL,
            headers: header,
            data : {

            }
          })
            .then((response) => {
              if (response.status !== 200) {
                return res.send(respone("500", response.data.result.data))
              } else {
                return res.send(respone("200", response.data.result.data))
              }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.log(error);
              return res.send(error)
            })
```

the error show

```
{
"message": "Request failed with status code 404",
"name": "AxiosError",
"config": {
    "transitional": {
        "silentJSONParsing": true,
        "forcedJSONParsing": true,
        "clarifyTimeoutError": false
    },
    "transformRequest": [
        null
    ],
    "transformResponse": [
        null
    ],
    "timeout": 0,
    "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
    "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
    "maxContentLength": -1,
    "maxBodyLength": -1,
    "env": {},
    "headers": {
        "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding": "application/json",
        "HTTP_API_KEY": "xxxx",
        "User-Agent": "axios/0.27.2",
        "Content-Length": 2
    },
    "method": "post",
    "url": "xxxxx",
    "data": "{}"
},
"code": "ERR_BAD_REQUEST",
"status": 404
}
```

Comment: Remove `headers` from your `headers` object and just put all the header values at the top level... `header = { 'HTTP_API_KEY': 'xxxxx' };` (FYI you probably don't need to manually specify the other two)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you nested your headers inside another "headers" property.
Basically you're doing this

```
headers: {
    headers: {
        'Content-Transfer-Encoding': ...
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry.. so what am I suppose todo, I try to adjust the header all the way
the result still same

Comment: Can you show what error specifically is thrown?

Comment: error showed in above, I've edited my question

Answer (score 0):

As Zai showed in her answer you problem is your header variable:

```
const header = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Transfer-Encoding': 'application/json',
            'content-type': 'application/json',
            'HTTP_API_KEY': 'xxxxx',
        }
    }
```

is nested, when you do this:

```
axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url: URL,
        headers: header,
        data : {

        }
```

what you are really doing is:

```
axios({
            method: 'POST',
            url: URL,
            headers:  headers: {
                'Content-Transfer-Encoding': 'application/json',
                'content-type': 'application/json',
                'HTTP_API_KEY': 'xxxxx',
            },
            data : {

            }
```

So your header: instead of being Content-transfer etc... is just 'headers'

try this:

```
const header = {
                'Content-Transfer-Encoding': 'application/json',
                'content-type': 'application/json',
                'HTTP_API_KEY': 'xxxxx',
            }
```

also, i recommend you to do a console.log with your api call in order to find this problems faster and compare with postman, really helpful in develop phase (just use it in local, never push that log to production)